# Filtering defaultdict on the base of value

Tags: python, defaultdict

Consider following default dict:

```
data = defaultdict(list)
data['key1'] = [{'check': '', 'sth1_1':'k1', 'sth1_2':'k2'}]
data['key2'] = [{'check': '0', 'sth2_1':'k3'}, {'check': 'asd', 'sth2_2':'k4'}, {'check':'1', 'sth2_3':'k5'}]
```

and so on..

I would like to filer out from `data` dictionaries (from data.values()) which value `'check' != '1'`

For given input above i'd expect:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key2': [{'sth2_3': 'k5', 'check': '1'}])
```

So far i've got:

```
for k, v in data.items():
    print "k, v: ", k, v
    v[:] = [d for d in v if d.get('check') == '1']
```

But it gives me output with unwanted `'key1': []` :

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'key2': [{'sth2_3': 'k5', 'check': '1'}], 'key1': []})
```

What would be the best pythonic way to solve that?

Comment: Why is `'key1': []` unwanted? When `d.get('check') == '1'` gives `False`, `v[:]` will be an empty list. Do you want delete `key1` then?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, i need to have the filtered dict to contain only key-value that meet stated condition..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is simple enough:

```
for k,v in data.items():
    filtered_vals = list(filter(lambda i: i['check'] == '1', v)
    if len(filtered_vals):
        data[k] = filtered_vals
    else:
        del data[k]
```

or if you're insane:

```
data = {k:v for k,v in { k:list(filter(lambda i: i['check'] == '1' ,v)) for k, v in data.items()}.items() if len(v)}
```

Comment: nice use of filter! FWIW, python lists have implicit boolean-ness.  so you can replace if len(x) with if x: when x is a list

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I figured five characters for additional clarity on what we are actually checking for would be good for readability.

Comment: It turned out finally that that i will have another rule of filtering too - solved it editing second line of Your solution to: `filtered_vals = list(filter(lambda i: i['check'] == '1' and i['check2'] in check_list, v))`   worked fine for now!

Answer (score 2):

This will do it in place.  It can be cleaned up a bit if you're okay making a new dictionary.

```
for key in data.keys():
    new_list = []
    for val in data[key]:
        if val['check'] == '1':
            new_list += [val]
    if new_list:
        data[key] = new_list
    else:
        del data[key]
```

If you really want to use (nested) comprehensions, this will work too:

```
d = {}
d = {key: [inner_dict for inner_dict in list_of_dicts if inner_dict['check'] == '1'] for key, list_of_dicts in data.iteritems()}
d = {key: val for key,val in d.iteritems() if val}
```